# update element in php foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I know this should be very simple, but boy I'm making a mess of it... would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

I've got an array which looks like this:

```
print_r($request_attributes['length']);

Array
(
    [0] => 28.00000
    [1] => 18.00000
)
```

and am trying to modify like so:

```
if(is_array($request_attributes['length'])) { 
    $request_attributes['length'] = $request_attributes['length'][0];
    print($request_attributes['length']);
    $request_attributes['length'] = $request_attributes['length'][1];
    print($request_attributes['length']);
}
```

which gives the correct output in the first update, but the second item outputs an '8'. I've tried the above in both a for and foreach which results in similar output for both this and the other two arrays ( width(8) and height(0) - they should result in 18.00000 and 13.00000 respectively ). So I guess I really have two questions:

**1. How do I update this(these) element(s)?**

**2. Where are the funny outputs actually coming from?**

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciated it.

Comment: When you are using `$request_attributes['length'][1]`, `length` is no longer an array since you changed it to a number - so what do you expect?

Comment: But even if I use something like: $request_attributes['length'] = array('length' => $request_attributes['length'][1]); - the second element will get the key but no value

Comment: True, as long as you overwrite $request_attributes['length'] ever and ever again.

Comment: can you show the actual foreach loop to put things in context? It's confusing what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at this. Your problem is, that you override you variable and in the second step $request_attributes['length'] is a string. Just define another var for your values.

```
$request_attributes['length'] = [
    28.000,
    18.000
];

$attributes = array();
if (is_array($request_attributes['length'])) {
    foreach ($request_attributes['length'] as $value) {
        $attributes[] = $value;
    }
}
```

As you see $attributes will contain all values of your $request_attributes['length'] array and will not be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Wish I had of asked earlier, could have saved myself a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

Define araay as below

```
$val=array([0]=>"18.000",[1]=>13.000)
```

then use

```
if(is_array($request_attributes['length'])) { 
$request_attributes['length'] = $val;
print_r($request_attributes['length']);
$request_attributes['length'] = $val;
print_r($request_attributes['length']);
}
```

Previously your array doesnt have any name.

Your print will only return Just array not the values

use

```
  print_r($request_attributes['length']) ;
```

instead

Comment: how will this work? `$request_attributes['length'] = $request_attributes['length'][0]` overwrites `$request_attributes['length']` so `$request_attributes['length'][1]` is then undefined

Comment: OO sorry i missed it, You cannot assign a value to an array, you can only assign value to array element.

Comment: no - I still only get the first item. I don't think this is too different to what I'm doing already.